# Android: how do I return an EditText line for a SearchView on ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview

I am setting up a SearchView on the AppBar and am able to set the Search icon successfully:

[image]

When the Search icon is clicked, the icon collapses as expected and I receive this:

[image]

I would like to see a traditional EditText line like this:

[image]

and then add a TextView to obtain this:

[image]

I tried many settings in xml file with no luck and tried to set up a custom view to show a TextView and the traditional EditText line using this example: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/better-user-interfaces-android-action-bar/
all with no luck.  Does not being able to override the default have something to do with the Theme I am using?  Or might it be due to default from 'app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"' in the layout?
What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<!-- Disable the theme-provided Action Bar.-->

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >

    <!-- Next two rows tell Android we're using the Toolbar instead of the Action Bar-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#C0C0C0</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c5c5c5</item>

</style>
</resources>

menu.xml
...
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Activity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"  />
```

Comment: I think it depends on Android OS version.